Problem maintaining a bluetooth connection on an ios app
I'm trying to create an application to exchange data with an ESP-32 but I can't keep the bluetooth connection when navigating between the pages of my application. I then tried to make a bluetooth context with "react" but without success. If anyone could help me, I'd be very grateful.
here's my BluetoothContext.tsx :
import React, { createContext, useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import { BleManager } from 'react-native-ble-plx';
import { atob } from 'react-native-quick-base64';

const SERVICE_UUID = '4fafc201-1fb5-459e-8fcc-c5c9c331914b';
const STEP_DATA_CHAR_UUID = 'beefcafe-36e1-4688-b7f5-00000000000b';

const initialState = {
  devices: [],
  scanning: false,
  connecting: false,
  connectedDevice: null,
  stepCount: 0,
  startScan: () => {},
  stopScan: () => {},
  connectToDevice: (device) => Promise.resolve(),
};

export const BluetoothContext = createContext(initialState);

export const BluetoothProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [devices, setDevices] = useState([]);
  const [scanning, setScanning] = useState(false);
  const [connecting, setConnecting] = useState(false);
  const [connectedDevice, setConnectedDevice] = useState(null);
  const [stepCount, setStepCount] = useState(0);
  const bleManager = useRef(new BleManager()).current;
  const deviceRef = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
      if (deviceRef.current) {
        deviceRef.current.cancelConnection().catch((error) => console.error('Disconnect error:', error));
        deviceRef.current = null;
      }
      bleManager.destroy();
    };
  }, [bleManager]);

  const startScan = () => {
    setDevices([]);
    setScanning(true);
    console.log('Scanning started...');
    bleManager.startDeviceScan(null, null, (error, scannedDevice) => {
      if (error) {
        console.error('Scan error:', error);
        setScanning(false);
        return;
      }
      if (scannedDevice.name) {
        setDevices((prevDevices) => {
          const existingDeviceIndex = prevDevices.findIndex((dev) => dev.id === scannedDevice.id);
          if (existingDeviceIndex !== -1) {
            prevDevices[existingDeviceIndex] = scannedDevice;
            return [...prevDevices];
          } else {
            return [...prevDevices, scannedDevice];
          }
        });
      }
    });
    setTimeout(() => stopScan(), 10000); // Stop scanning after 10 seconds
  };

  const stopScan = () => {
    console.log('Scanning stopped.');
    bleManager.stopDeviceScan();
    setScanning(false);
  };

  const connectToDevice = async (device) => {
    try {
      setConnecting(true);
      await stopScan();
      const connectedDevice = await device.connect();
      setConnectedDevice(connectedDevice);
      deviceRef.current = connectedDevice;
      await connectedDevice.discoverAllServicesAndCharacteristics();
      const services = await connectedDevice.services();
      const service = services.find((s) => s.uuid === SERVICE_UUID);
      const characteristics = await service.characteristics();
      const stepDataCharacteristic = characteristics.find((c) => c.uuid === STEP_DATA_CHAR_UUID);

      stepDataCharacteristic.monitor((error, char) => {
        if (error) {
          console.error('Error monitoring:', error);
          return;
        }
        const rawStepData = atob(char.value);
        const stepCount = parseInt(rawStepData, 10);
        setStepCount(stepCount);
      });

      setConnecting(false);
      console.log('Connected to:', connectedDevice.name);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Connection error:', error);
      setConnecting(false);
    }
  };

  return (
    <BluetoothContext.Provider
      value={{
        devices,
        scanning,
        connecting,
        connectedDevice,
        stepCount,
        startScan,
        stopScan,
        connectToDevice,
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </BluetoothContext.Provider>
  );
};


_layout.tsx :

import { Stack } from 'expo-router';

export default function RootLayout() {
  return (
    <Stack
      screenOptions={{
        headerStyle: {
          backgroundColor: '#FFFFF0',
        },
        headerTintColor: '#000',
        headerTitleStyle: {
          fontWeight: 'bold',
        },
      }}>
      <Stack.Screen name="index" />
      <Stack.Screen name="BluetoothConnectionPage" />
    </Stack>
  );
}


index.tsx :
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Image } from "react-native";
import React from "react";
import { Link } from "expo-router";


export default function Page() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.main}>
        <Image source={require('./assets/images/xxxx.png')} style={styles.logo} />
        <Text style={styles.title}>Bienvenue</Text>
        <Text style={styles.subtitle}>Cette application vous aidera à xxxxxx.</Text>
        <Link href={'/BluetoothConnectionPage'} asChild>
          <Text style={styles.link}>Go to connexion page</Text>
        </Link>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    marginTop: 30,
    flex: 0.9,
    alignItems: "center",
    padding: 24,
  },
  main: {
    flex: 0.8,
    justifyContent: "center",
    maxWidth: 960,
    marginHorizontal: "auto",
  },
  logo: {
    width: 140,
    height: 110,
    marginBottom: 50,
    alignSelf: 'center', // Center the logo
  },
  title: {
    fontSize: 60,
    fontWeight: "bold",
    textAlign: "center",
    marginBottom: 20,
  },
  subtitle: {
    fontSize: 20,
    color: "#38434D",
    textAlign: "center",
    marginBottom: 30,
  },
  link: {
    fontSize: 18,
    color: "#1E90FF",
    marginTop: 20,
    textAlign: "center",
  },
});



